# Array de imágenes guarda en la bbdd unicamente el último elemento

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Antes de empezar, querría enseñarles mi modelo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el modelo products y el product_images con una clave foránea para la múltiple subidas de imágenes.

En el modelo ya tengo hecha las relaciones de Product a ProductImage hasMany y de ProductImage a Product belongsTo.

Actualmente estoy haciendo el método de crear productos con sus respetivas imágenes y

Tengo un array de imágenes:

```
 <input id="image" multiple="multiple" type="file" class="form-control" name="image[]"/>
```

Y mediante el método save las estoy guardando:

```
$category_id = $request->get('categoria_id');
        $name = $request->input('name');
        $brand = $request->input('brand');
        $price = $request->input('price');
        $files = $request->file('image');

        $product = new Product();
        $product->category_id = $category_id;
        $product->name = $name;
        $product->brand = $brand;
        $product->price = $price;

        $product->save();

        //Instancia de ProductImage
        $product_image = new ProductImage();
        if ($files && is_array($files) || $files && is_object($files)) {

            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $file_name = time() . " ". $file->getClientOriginalName();
                //Ya que vamos a guardar las imagenes en la tabla Product_images y no en la de Product
                //Tenemos que recoger el ID de product y hacer otro insert dentro de esa tabla
                $product_image->product_id = $product->id;

                //Guardar img
                $product_image->image = $file_name;

                //Hacemos el save
                $product_image->save();

                \Storage::disk('products')->put($file_name, \File::get($file));
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('product.all')->with(['message' => 'Imagenes no subidas']);
        }
        
        return redirect()->route('product.all')->with(['message' => 'Producto creado!!']);
```

El caso es que a pesar del ForEach para recorrer todos los elementos del array tipo archivo que lo contienen únicamente me guarda el último elemento recorrido en la bbdd en lugar de todos.

¿Alguien me puede echar un cable? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Y si creas la instancia de `ProductImage()` dentro del ciclo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como puedes observar en la [doc. de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models), el método `save()`

- Se invoca cuando se crea la instancia de la clase modelo
- Nos sirve para crear **un** nuevo registro que será almacenado en la base de datos

Entonces por cada registro del modelo `ProductImage` dicha instancia debe ser creada, por tanto debería alcanzar con modificar tu código de esta manera:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    /* Resto de tu código */
    
    $product_image = new ProductImage();

    $file->columna1 = $product_image->clave1;
    $file->columna2 = $product_image->clave2;
    $file->columna3 = $product_image->clave3;
    $file->save();

    /* Resto de tu código */
}
```

Comment: Resuelto!! gracias